# Regularized 2F1 hypergeometric in R

Tags: r, wolfram-mathematica

In Mathematica wolfram there is a function to calculate hypergeometric 2F1() function. For example in Mathematica two calculation are as follows:

```
in:   Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[15, 8, 10, -0.651542]
out:  7.86105*10^-9
in:   Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[31, 13, 18, -2.651542]
out:  5.04779*10^-26
```

In R I tried following equivalent but results are not similar with above:

```
library("BAS")
> hypergeometric2F1(15, 8 ,10, -0.651542,log=F )
[1] 2.441767e-05
> hypergeometric2F1(31, 13, 18, -2.651542,log=F)
[1] Inf
Warning message:
In hypergeometric2F1(31, 13, 18, -2.651542, log = F) :
  integral in 2F1 diverges
```

I want to know what is the exact equivalent of Mathematica's Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[] function in R.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
hypergeometric2F1(15, 8, 10, -0.651542, log = FALSE) / factorial(10 - 1)
[1] 7.861054e-09
```

because the regularized version is `2F1(a,b,c;z) / Gamma(c)`.